# Magnetic Field of Earth and Turbulence of plasma

Tags: magnetic-fields, earth, plasma-physics, turbulence

We generally know that plasma turbulence creates magnetic field (here, I have assumed that it happens through the dynamo effect). it is also affected by magnetic fields. Is it possible that plasma turbulence could be fluctuated by the earth's magnetic field, if so, does it have any applications (like help generate more plasma turbulence through the magnetic field).

Comment: So currents are the source for magnetic fields, not plasma turbulence.  Plasma turbulence can cascade to small scales and ultimately end up generating thin current sheets, but there needs to be some large-scale driver to force the turbulence in the first place.  Also, turbulence tends to have $\delta B/B$ < 1, so the large background field of Earth's intrinsic dipole (I know it's not an exact dipole) will act as a guide field, not a fluctuating source unless it's strongly perturbed by some transient like an interplanetary shock.